# Send commands to parent shell

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd, console-application

So you are in your favorite shell (which can be cmd.exe, powershell, bash, etc.) and look at this:

```
C:\>
```

There, you have my fancy app `WaescherApp.exe`.

So if you run it like this ...

```
C:\>WaescherApp.exe --anyArgument
```

... this app does anything and decides that the parent shell should execute a command and closes itself (the app, not the console host) immediately again. This command could be changing to a directory with `cd C:\anypath\` or execute a command like `git add .` or any other command you can imagine.

The result should be that the shell we started with ends up with that command executed and to take that example again changed to the directory that app determined:

```
C:\>
C:\>WaescherApp.exe --anyArgument
C:\anypath\>
```

Now, does anyone have an idea how this can be done from the app? I tried things like starting a process and sending commands to the `StandardInput`, etc. but I cound not get it working because that does not affect the parent shell, of course.

Edit: Please note that I'm not searching for powershell scripts but a possibility to "talk" to the hosting console (which might be a powershell host) from a .NET console application.

Comment: Unconditional inversion of control across process boundaries is a dangerous idea, I'd be terrified if my console worked this way.

Comment: You can't do this, and for good reason.

Comment: Depending on what Waescher.exe is actually supposed to do, you could write a bash script / batch file that would have the same effect, though. ( 1. Call Waecher with argument, 2. call / execute that argument)

Comment: I believe that the link above summarize well enough why it can't be done and the possible way around it.

Comment: Interesting to see how everyone points to security concerns. If the developer's intention is to do harm to the system, he does not have to use the console for that. By starting the exe, it runs with the same priviledges as the console owns, and if a console would be really required to do harm, there's noone stopping the developer to call ’cmd.exe /k "any command"’ from his app. This new console process runs with inherited priviledges and can even be hidden from the user ...

Comment: That only holds true if the parent process is elevated

Comment: And if not, the child process is not elevated as well. Same context, even same user context

Comment: You can write to the console input buffer via `WriteConsoleInput` and exit. The parent process (typically a shell) will read this from its `StandardInput` as the next command to execute. Presumably you either inherited or have the right to attach to the console, so there's no security concern. However, I'd be concerned that it's an inherently fragile design that breaks if your process is run from an unsupported shell or without an attached console.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen would you please reopen that question? That answer you linked to does not help me since I'm not even using powershell - I'm running a .NET Console.

Comment: @eryksun That sounds promising, thank you. I tried different thinks with the StandardInput of processes but could not get it to work. I'll try the `WriteConsoleInput ` soon.

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned it would be a big security issue if you could control a console from within an application like that.

You could, however, write a batch file that does something similar. Then you would be restricted to using PS or CMD, of course.

Comment: I would love to hear about that "big security issue" you mentioned.

Comment: Okay, so what happens if I decide to run a process with different privileges than that of my current console session? By giving that software the possibility to control the my console session I directly make it possible for it to gain more access privileges than it maybe is supposed to have? Explain this to me.

Comment: Okay. Give me a concrete example on how you would plan to do this.